# Restsharp to Post An xml file to an api

Tags: c#, api, winforms, flask, restsharp

I have a WindowsForm ADO.NET application that will use a post method call to a Flask api and upload an xml file

here is how i call the api using python :

```
import requests

API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000'

with open('result.xml') as fp:
    content = fp.read()

response = requests.post(
    '{}/files/result.xml'.format(API_URL), data=content
)
```

i've been looking on how to call the api with method post and uplaod a file in c# windows form

here is what i end up with :

the upload function :

```
private async Task<IRestResponse> UploadAsync(string fileName, string server)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(server);
            var request = new RestRequest("/files", Method.POST);
            
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            // init XMLDocument and load customer in it
            doc = new XmlDocument();    
            doc.Load(@""+fileName+"");
            // Update (PUT) customer
            request = new RestRequest("/files", Method.POST);
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddParameter("text/xml;charset=utf-8", doc.InnerXml, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return response;  
        }
```

the function call :

```
 private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label1.Text))
            {
                string url = "http://localhost:5000";
                IRestResponse restResponse = await UploadAsync(label1.Text,url);
                if (restResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully uploaded the file", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

clicking the button does not do anything
no errors and it doesn't send the file

any idea on how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this problem i used this code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(@""+textBox1.Text+"");
                var client = new RestClient("http://appapi9.azurewebsites.net/files/filethatillcheck.xml");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
                request.AddParameter("application/xml",""+doc.OuterXml+"", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                MessageBox.Show("done");
```

i had to load the xml file and send it's content